# New CPU installed. fTPM NV corrupted or fTPM NV structure changed

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, ftpm

When I try to boot up my PC, I get an American Megatrends Screen, telling me `New CPU installed. fTPM NV corrupted or fTPM NV structure changed`. I have not installed a new CPU, and do not know what fTPM NV is. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does [FIX: New CPU installed. fTPM NV corrupted or fTPM NV structure changed in Windows 10/11. - wintips.org - Windows Tips & How-tos](https://www.wintips.org/fix-new-cpu-installed-ftpm-nv-corrupted-or-ftpm-nv-structure-changed-in-windows-10-11/) help?

Comment: Thank you very much!